# `read-event`: How to cancel a mouse event once read

Tags: mouse, events

**Q**:  `read-event`:  How to cancel a mouse event once read?

As to a generic keyboard keystroke, `read-event` reads the event *without* executing the command that the key is bound to.  E.g., calling `read-event` and pressing `SPC` will *not* cause Emacs to execute `self-insert-command`.

As to `mouse-1`, `read-event` reads the event *and* executes the command that the key is bound to.

The following example creates a simple `mouse-1` infinity loop to demonstrate the concept.  The function `signal` does not break the infinity loop.  It is not a `recursive-edit` situation, so `top-level` is inapplicable.  The function `discard-input` has no effect here.  Setting the following variables to `nil` have no effect here:  `unread-command-events`, `last-command-event` and `last-input-event`.  Through trial and error and sheer luck, I found that `read-key-sequence-vector` will serve to gobble up the event to achieve the desired outcome.  Perhaps there is a proper way to handle this issue that does not involve calling `read-key-sequence-vector`.

```lisp
(global-set-key [mouse-1] 'mouse-1--func)

(defun mouse-1--func (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((event (read-event "Please press mouse-1 again.")))
    ;;; GOBBLE THE EVENT
    ;; (read-key-sequence-vector nil)
    (message "mouse-1--func:  %s" event)))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.  When I try your code in `emacs -Q`, what I see in `*Messages*` seems to indicate that `mouse-1` events are not mentioned - I see only `down-mouse-1` events printed there.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for having a look a this particular thread.  Your observation is correct.  The goal is to prevent `mouse-1--func` from running *after* `(read-event)` returns something like `(down-mouse-1 (#<window 3 on *scratch*> 445 (317 . 283) 9803230 nil 445 (44 . 11) nil (23 . 129) (7 . 14)))`.  I was unable to find any `abort`-like mechanism, so I had to resort to using `read-key-sequence-vector` to create the desired result of aborting / preventing `mouse-1--func` from running again.  E.g., break the infinity loop with the mouse key, but do not run the function attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you click on the mouse, two events are generated. In this case `down-mouse-1` and `mouse-1`.

Your code consumes `down-mouse-1`, but leaves the second in the queue.

If you consume both, the problem goes away.

For example:

```
(defun mouse-1--func (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((event (read-event "Please press mouse-1 again.")))
    ;;; GOBBLE THE EVENT
    ;; (read-key-sequence-vector nil)
    (message "mouse-1--func:  %s" event)
    (when (eq (car-safe event) 'down-mouse-1)
      (let ((event2 (read-event "And a second")))
        (message "Second event: %s" event2)))))
```

Of course, you will need to generalize and add safeguards (e.g. what happens if the second event doesn't match the first).